# Minecraft color codes not working properly (Spigot)

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm using this:

```
public void onPlayerCommandPreprocessEvent(PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent event) {
    event.getPlayer().sendRawMessage(Color.RED.toString()+"TEXT...");
}
```

but it appears as `Color:[rgb0xFF00]TEXT...` in the Chat.

I also tried `getPlayer().sendMessage(...)` and `Color.RED`, but neither is working.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**: I found the solution, see my answer below.

Comment: The text should appear in red instead of showing the "Color:[rgb0x...]"

Comment: Try sending ANSI color red instead "\u001B[31m"   Let me know...

Comment: Actually I would rather avoid that because the use of hard coded color codes is deprecated since they changed to JSON in 1.9, at least I was told so.

Comment: I don't know where the color codes are stored, but to avoid hard-coding it, you just have to read the file where they were stored and work from there. Check my answer

Comment: I found the solution: I was using org.bukkit.Color instead of org.bukkit.ChatColor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. You have to use org.bukkit.ChatColor instead of org.bukkit.Color! (Stupid me)

So:

```
public void onPlayerCommandPreprocessEvent(PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent event) {
    event.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.RED+"TEXT...");
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `toString()`, Just ChatColor.RED + "TEXT" is ok

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Formatting_codes), you need to send a specific text code, not just a color. Make a function like this:

```
String getColorCode(Color c){
    switch(c){
        case Color.RED:
            return "§c";
        case Color.BLACK:
            return "§0";
        // each color code can be found at http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Formatting_codes
    }
    return "";
}
```

And then call this function for your message:

```
public void onPlayerCommandPreprocessEvent(PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent event) {
    event.getPlayer().sendRawMessage(getColorCode(Color.RED) + "TEXT...");
}
```

Comment: But isn't that exactly what the built-in org.bukkit.ChatColor is for?

Comment: No clue, I have never touched Minecraft's API

Comment: Thanks anyway, I found the solution: I was using org.bukkit.Color instead of org.bukkit.ChatColor